# about vue-cli refresh page,the page show lot of errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <，

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm new to vue, and I use vue-cli to build a project, and turn the mode to history in router/index.js. When I run it locally，it does work and shows no errors, but when I release it on the server, it does work too. However, when I go to the next page, and I refresh the page, it doesn't work,and shows many errors.

The normal page:
[image: the normal page]

and when I refresh the page,the page become

[image: error page]

and my code in router/index.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import Router from 'vue-router';
 import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
 import Login from '@/views/login/login';
 import List from '@/views/main/gift_list';
 import Detail from '@/views/main/gift_detail';


 Vue.use(Router);
 Vue.use(VueResource);



 export default new Router({
   mode: 'history',
   base: '/gift',
   routes: [
    {
       path: '/login',
       meta: {
         title: '登录'
       },
       name: 'Login',
       component: Login
     },{
       path: '/list',
       meta: {
         title: '礼品册商城'
      },
       name: 'List',
       component: List
     },{
       path: '/detail/:code',
       meta: {
         title: '礼品详情'
       },
       name: 'Detail',
       component: Detail
     }
   ]
 })
```

and my code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/jf_gift.min.css">
    <title>礼品册商城</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/jf_gift.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/common.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/md5-2.js"></script>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

hope someone can help me